# Can't bend svg image to a curve using simple deform

Tags: svg

I imported a naruto cloud svg image and wanted it to curve around the bowl. I tried using the simple deform modifier to bend it however it doesnt work. Also despite selecting all the svg image to bend, only one is affected as shown in the picture. Does anyone know how to get it to curve around the bowl? Heres the link to my file, thank you! https://pasteall.org/blend/1e855fda1c984ba68096748d810d4209              [image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the object don´t have the proper geometry. Meaning it doesn't have enough faces. It needs to have square faces or triangles to bend properly. Normally some are comprised of just one big face.

Comment: so how do I do that? Do i just put ctr R?

Comment: You select the front faces and subdive them with the subdivide command